# Wegihts for ViT-G/14 or ViT-L/16

Tags: computer-vision

I have been trying to find model weights for the above mentioned models, especially ViT-G/14 but have been unable to find it. The models are mentioned here https://paperswithcode.com/sota/image-classification-on-imagenet and there is a repository from google linked: https://github.com/google-research/big_vision, so I am not sure why I can't find the weights. Has anybody used any of these models and could help me?

Thank you and I am sorry if this is not a great question, I have just started getting into machine learning.

Comment: The model weights depend on the task that you are training it on.  ViT-G/14 is an architecture, not a model.  It's not clear what you are asking for.  Perhaps you are asking for a pre-trained model, that has been pre-trained on Imagenet.  I don't know if that question is on-topic here.